iPhone 14 is not playing this audio, used ffmpeg to increase volume in audio
I recorded an audio using Audacity, then increased its volume 10 times using ffmpeg. When I am sending this audio as attachment to my friends to test, then people with older iPhones are able to hear it fine (volume is still low though), but people on iPhone 14 and higher are not hearing my voice in the mp3 at all.
Actually, on iPhone 14 and higher, my voice is there in audio, but its so low in volume that it's almost inaudible, impossible to hear. I can hear it if I strain really really a lot. Other things on the phone are playing fine, audio settings are showing full.
If I add a background music to the audio using ffmpeg, then people on iPhone 14 and higher are only hearing the music, not my voice.
What is happening here?
Edit: This is certainly a ffmpeg issue. I increased volume in input file using audacity and tried playing the new file on iPhone 14, it has somewhat higher volume, can hear myself a little but still not much. In any case, whatever Audacity did to increase volume, that worked, and whatever ffmpeg is doing with my below command, it's not working at all.
My question is: Do I need to adjust some frequency etc options/settings in the input when using ffmpeg to increase the volume? What ffmpeg command can I use to fix the issue, so that volume increased files play on all devices?
Thanks
Here is the ffmpeg command I am using to increase volume in my recorded audio. Output mp3 file from below command is uploaded here:
https://tbrjar.com/audio_test/z1.mp3
and here's the original input file as recorded by audacity:
https://tbrjar.com/audio_test/input.mp3
% ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i input.mp3 -to 00:00:05 -filter:a "volume=10" -c:a libmp3lame z1.mp3
    
ffmpeg version 2024-03-04-git-e30369bc1c-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkg
    conf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-icon
    v --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --e
    nable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh -
    -enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sd
    l2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdav
    s2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --en
    able-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvi
    d --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-
    mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-li
    bfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-l
    ibvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-
    ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable
    -libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl
    --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enabl
    e-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --e
    nable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --e
    nable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --ena
    ble-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmys
    ofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
      libavutil      58. 40.100 / 58. 40.100
      libavcodec     60. 41.100 / 60. 41.100
      libavformat    60. 23.100 / 60. 23.100
      libavdevice    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
      libavfilter     9. 17.100 /  9. 17.100
      libswscale      7.  6.100 /  7.  6.100
      libswresample   4. 14.100 /  4. 14.100
      libpostproc    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
    Input #0, mp3, from 'luck1.mp3':
      Duration: 00:00:54.02, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 133 kb/s
      Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (mp3float), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 133 kb/s
          Metadata:
            encoder         : LAME3.100
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    Output #0, mp3, to 'z1.mp3':
      Metadata:
        TSSE            : Lavf60.23.100
      Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
          Metadata:
            encoder         : Lavc60.41.100 libmp3lame
    [out#0/mp3 @ 00000000001a7340] video:0KiB audio:79KiB subtitle:0KiB other stream
    s:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: 0.313639%
    size=      79KiB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 129.5kbits/s speed=18.2x


The question seems to ask several things at once, do you want to know why a track only plays on certain iPhones, why Audacity works differently than ffmpeg or how to boost volume with ffmpeg? Please edit the question to focus on the specifc problem you want to solve (and remove the parts not relevant), it will increase your chance of getting useful answers.

@nohillside I simply wanted to provide all the steps I took and tried to get things working. I want to know why ffmpeg volume increased files are not working on some devices and what ffmpeg command I can use to fix the issue. I'll edit the question with this info. Thanks

General remark: The best way to get good audio is to start with a good recording, fixing things afterwards can't resolve issues like low volume without introducing noise etc. Looking at the question: I can hear your voice just fine in the z1 file on macOS. Which versions of iOS are used on the various phones you test this with, which app is used for playback? What did user Hydranix propose (link is broken) and how does this not fix the issue?

@nohillside My father has an I-phone 14+ bought just recently, I'm not sure what the IOS is on that. The increased volume audio file is not playing fine on that phone, my recorded voice comes out so low its like insects buzzing. The increased volume audio is working fine on other older iphones. hydranix gave me 3 files to test (modifying my original input.mp3). The AIFF extension file given by Hydranix worked fine even on 14+ iphone, I don't know how he fixed it. Hydranix never told how he fixed the file, only gave 3 files to test, which he seems to have deleted now, not sure why...

It will be difficult to come up with answers if the question lacks relevant details.

Hi @nohillside let me know what other info is needed. I have linked to the original and modified files, given the ffmpeg command, explained the problem also as best as I could have. I will try to post whatever else info is needed to solve this. I tried to convert my original mp3 to AIFF format, like hydranix uploaded file, but my AIFF converted file is also not working. Even audacity modified files are not playing as well as the file given by hydranix. I don't know what he did to modify the file to make it work in iphone 14 plus.

See comments above for things which might be relevant. Details matter here.
